# How to retain <select> tag values when changing the number of displayed elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I use a first select dropdown to choose how many age selection elements to generate. For example:

[image: kids]

would cause 4 elements to be generated.  Say I then choose some values.

[image]

If I then change the number of selected elements, I want to keep the values in any existing elements.  For example, if I change the number of elements to 6, I want 6 elements with the first 4 keeping their selected values.

And I would like the new selects to appear horizontally

```
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Kids:</label>
        <%--
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Minors" value="<%=(package!= null && package.request!=null)? package.request.Minors :0 %>"/>
        </div>--%>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="chosen-select" style="width: 350px;" name="Minors" id="cbo-select">
                <%for (int i = 0; i <= maxKids; i++)   
                { %>
                    <option value="<%=i %>" name="Minors"><%=i%></option>
                    Minors = i;
                <% } %>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="area">                     
    </div>
```

**//////////// javascript

```
function selectedElementChanged() {
    <%var ageKids = (int) ViewData["ageKids"];%>
    var ageKids = '<%=ageKids%>';

    //$(".chosen-select").area.empty();
    //$(".chosen-select").area.append('<select style="width: 20%;" name="KidAges" id="auto-select" class="chosen-select">' +
    //                 '</select>');

    var selectedValue = $("#cbo-select").val();
    $("#area").empty();
    if (parseInt(selectedValue)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue; i++) {
            $("#area")
                   .append('<select class="form-control chosen-select" style="width: 20%;" name="KidAges" id="auto-select">' +
                       '</select>');
        }
        var  i = 0;
        if (i >= 0) {
            $("select[name='KidAges']")
                   .append('<option value ="0" name = "KidAges[0]" > < 1 </option></br>');
        } 
        for (i = 1; i <= ageKids; i++) {
            $("select[name='KidAges']").append('<option value=' + i + ' name="KidAges[' + i + ']" > ' + i + '</option>');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " save in a list in the controller" ? What does it mean?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Please show your code on how you are generating the number of selects you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To maintain the existing dropdown values you must either store/restore values when repopulating the list or incrementally add/remove controls.  The latter seems more efficient.

```
var desiredCount = $("#cbo-select").val();
desiredCount = parseInt(desiredCount);

var area = $("#area");
var controls = area.children();
if (desiredCount) {
    var currentCount = controls.length;
    if (desiredCount < currentCount) {
        controls.slice(desiredCount).remove();
    } else {
        for (var ii = currentCount; ii < desiredCount; ++ii) {
            area.append('<select class="form-control chosen-select" style="width: 20%;" name="KidAges" id="auto-select">' +
                '</select>');
        }        
    }
} else {
    area.empty();
}
```